# Delay of 1 to 2 seconds occur before open Splash scree in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, splash-screen, android-launcher

I face a bug in the start of my app when the splash screen is open. There is 1 to 2 seconds delay occur before launched the splash screen. Here i provide the link of video please check how it behave:

[Preview of launching splash screen](http://saadusman.androidstudent.net/splash_scree_test.mp4)

Here is the AndroidManiseft code to launched splash screen:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/customStyleForSplash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And here is the code of "SplashActivity":

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(MySharedPref.getInstance(SplashActivity.this).isUserSetLocation()){
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ContainerActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LocationOptionsActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, 2000);

}
```

}

Please suggest me the possible solutions. Thanks

Comment: It is a commong problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437037/android-prevent-white-screen-at-startup

Comment: @i30mb1 Thank you so much. This link is helpful for me.